# Not seeing Azure Service Fabric application with Docker support template in Azure DevOps Portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am following steps mentioned in [Azure DevOps Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-container-app-with-cicd-vsts)

**It says:**

1. Select the Pipelines option on the left panel, then click New Pipeline
2. Select Azure Repos Git as source, your Team project name, your project Repository, and master Default branch or manual and scheduled builds. Then click Continue.
3. In Select a template, select the Azure Service Fabric application with Docker support template and click Apply.

At this point, I am not seeing "**Azure Service Fabric application with Docker support template**".

This is what I see :
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image: enter code here]

**Am i missing something?**

Answer (score 0):

The example is for the Classic Editor and you chose the `.yaml` templates.

After you click on "New Pipeline" you need to click on the "Use the classic editor" in the bottom:

[image]

Then, choose the repo and click "continue" and you will see the "Service Fabric" template:

[image]